# trouble with a function that do not return the values expected in php

Tags: php, function, variables, return

I met some trouble, In fact I would like to separate the code treatment of php of the html code that just display something expected.

So for that I started to give all my treatment in php function.

One of them looks like this:

```
<?php 

/**
 * FONCTION DE CREATION DES ANNONCES (page add-annonce.php)
 *  
 */

function saveAnnonce($form, $annonce, $to, $session) {
    $sql = "SELECT `nom`,`prenom`, FROM `gestionnaire` WHERE `id`='{$session}'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $donnees = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (isset($form)) {

        $by = $donnees['nom'] . ' ' . $donnees['prenom'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `cometchat_announcements` SET
    `announcement`  ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($annonce) . "',
    `by`            ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($by) . "',
    `time`          ='" . mysql_real_escape_string(time()) . "',
    `to`            ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($to) . "'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<div class=\"success\">L'annonce a bien été ajoutée , vous pouvez continuer vos actions<br>La mise à jour interviendra après actualisation</div>";
        echo "<SCRIPT type=\"text/javascript\"> 
<!-- 
alert(\"Ajout d\'une nouvelle annonce : Ok !\");
// --> 
</SCRIPT> ";
    }
};

if(isset($_POST['enreg']))
{
   saveAnnonce($_POST['enreg'], $_POST['annonce'],$_POST['to'], $_SESSION['id']);
}
     ?>
```

the trouble is with the first function, that select that should return $donnees using the first query.

When I try to use it in the econd function, it does not work, in fact it display something blank, but I'm sure the first query does return the good values expected.

So I do not understand why if I return $donnees which is the mysql_fetch_assoc of the mysql_query for the first function. Why When I type $donnees['nom'] it display something blank?

In fact it display nothing. But I'm sure at 100% the values exists.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have an extra `,` in the query after `\`prenom\``. You need to check for errors, it would have told you there was a syntax error.

Comment: oh thanks, I was looking for this since few times, didn't see that it was of the coma

Comment: But since `mysql_query` was returning an error, why did you expect `$donnees` to contain anything?

Comment: in fact it does not return any errors, I have configured my ubuntu for returning errors, but it does not display anything.

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns `false` when there's an error, then you use `mysql_error()` to get the error message. It doesn't report errors using PHP's built-in error reporting.